# mongodb aggregate $nin condition with another collection

Tags: mysql, mongodb

```
SELECT * FROM collection1 c1 WHERE c1.mobileNum NOT IN(SELECT mobileNumer FROM collection2) ORDER by c1.createdAt DESC 

collection 1 :
=============
[{
name: 'abc',
mobileNum: 1234,
createdAt: DateTime
},{
name: 'efg',
mobileNum: 5678,
createdAt: DateTime
},
{
name: 'ijk',
mobileNum: 222222,
createdAt: DateTime
},
{
name: 'mno',
mobileNum: 33333,
createdAt: DateTime
}
]
collection 2 :
=============
[{
age: 24,
mobileNumer : 1234,
createdAt: DateTime
},{
age: 25,
mobileNumer : 0000,
createdAt: DateTime
},
{
age: 25,
mobileNumer : 1111,
createdAt: DateTime
}]
```

first have the mysql query.
second i have the mongodb collections are collection1 and collection 2.
need to convert the mysql statement into equivalent mongodb aggregate query.
can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

1. `$lookup` - Join collection 1 (`mobileNum`)  with collection 2 (`mobileNumer`).
2. `$match` - Filter document with `matchedDocs` is empty array (`$size`: 0).
3. `$sort` - Sort by `createdAt` descending.
4. `$unset` - Remove `matchedDocs` field.

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "col2",
      "localField": "mobileNum",
      "foreignField": "mobileNumer",
      "as": "matchedDocs"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "matchedDocs": {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "matchedDocs"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x3fhDvO2g7H)